# Eliminating Delay on HTML popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I understand that Chrome runs the entire program asynchronously which causes my extension to open about 2 seconds after being clicked. Is there a way to force the extension to display the html page with a 'loading' message and then finishing loading the javascript and replacing the loading message with content without having them run at the same time?

I've looked into onload but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just wrap my code into `setTimeout`, seems to cure some delay:

```
setTimeout(start, 0);

function start() {
    //everything
}
```

Comment: I've implemented it but it pops up with an empty box first and then populates it a second later. Am I just not putting it into the right place? What should it encompass?

Comment: I've adjusted the value of settimeout to 50 milliseconds. This seems to have fixed it. Thanks serg!

Comment: I have contentscript.js, popup.js and some script file for AngularJs, which part of code should be wrapped in setTimeout?